# Assign terms to image field items

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, media

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

1) The website has a gallery page which is made from one node, so each time uploading new images to the gallery, you just edit this one node.

2) EVA is attached to the node page, so images are rendered via Views using EVA on that node page.

3) It all works great and everything. But it needs this feature that some of those images needs to be featured at the home page with a slideshow. So to achieve all that we can use Views and etc. But how do I filter out which images to show? All images cannot be shown.

4) So when uploading images to the image_field it would be nice if you could somehow select (I was thinking tick/untick boxes for each item in the image field) which ones to show in the homepage slideshow.

5) To be more exact, I was thinking maybe you could somehow assign some taxonomy vocab called 'Featured' which would have terms 'Yes' and 'No'. So you tick 'Yes' to all images you want to be shown in the slideshow and then just apply those filters via Views.

But I cannot figure out how to do that part where you assign terms to image field items without writing custom modules, not a PHP guru, sadly. Also any other alternatives are welcome.

UPDATE: I came up with a nasty workaround by using image field Alt or Title fields for filtering out via Views, it does the job, but from SEO point-of-view this is wrong. I put 'featured' value in Alt field for images I want to show up on the homepage slideshow, but that's wrong from SEO position, because Alt field should contain unique titles for each images for search engines to read it. Tagging them all as 'featured' is misleading.

So that's what I'm looking for, would be nice if you could add tick boxes next to Alt and Title fields. I tried image_field_caption module, it adds custom textarea field next to Alt and Title, but has no Views support, and again, you need to write 'feature' for each image instead of ticking it.

All this makes more sense now though.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a field collection instead of the straight up image field. The field collection would have an image field and a term reference, plus maybe more things once you see its power.
The trade off is that your views will become a bit more cumbersome to build, but only slightly.